# TSQL datediff returning same result for week and days

Tags: t-sql

Why is the datediff for the week and day returning the same results for week and day?

This is the query I am using;

```
select DATEDIFF("D",[ARRS-DATE], GETDATE()) daysdiff ,DATEDIFF("W",[ARRS-DATE], GETDATE()) weeksdiff,*  from [RE-ARRS-HIST]
```

Any ideas on what can be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`"w"` is not shorthand for weeks, it is an alias for `WEEKDAY`.  Since Weekday does not really make sense as a datediff option, I would guess that this is treated like days under the hood.

If you want weeks difference, you need to use `"ww"` or `"wk"`. Or better still use the full version `WEEK`, it is much more clear, and is not much harder to write at all.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY, [ARRS-DATE], GETDATE()) AS daysdiff,
        DATEDIFF(WEEK, [ARRS-DATE], GETDATE()) AS weeksdiff
FROM    [RE-ARRS-HIST];
```

[Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: Aside: [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't mention support for _datepart_ "weekday" ("dw", "w"), but it "works". It does support "dayofyear" ("dy", "y"), though what that means for a date difference isn't absolutely clear.